# Is there a way to connect to a Raspberry server with only bluetooth?

Tags: networking, bluetooth

Let's say I installed an API on my raspberry pi (with Php, python, it doesn't matter).
Is there a way for my Android phone to make direct requests on my API through Bluetooth ? (If my raspberry and my phone are not connected to internet with Wifi, Ethernet or 4G)

Comment: You might be able to get the two devices tethered via BT. Or maybe you can configure the Pi as an accessory and create an Android app to interface with it. It depends on how much time you are willing to spend setting this up.

Comment: Time is not a problem, I just want to know a method to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is!

For a Python example see this GitHub repo:

https://gist.github.com/keithweaver/3d5dbf38074cee4250c7d9807510c7c3

Comment: I'm not convinced this answer will be true in some cases. IMHO, Bluetooth on RPI is "not ready for prime time". Personally, I've found it to be buggy and recalcitrant in operation. Just my opinion...